# How to upload to Nexus OSS without having the filename changed in the file system?

Tags: maven, repository, naming-conventions, nexus

Is it possible to upload a file into Nexus (Open Source Version) without having its filename changed?  By change I mean where uploaded file does not take the format *artifactId-version-classifier* but just kept its original file name.

For example: if I were you upload a file called t01.jar to nexus with the groupId being computerScience, the artifactId being Assignment1, and the version number being 1.0, the uploaded file would have a new file name *Assignment1-1.0.jar* but I want the file to retain its name *t01.jar*.

Is it possible for me to retain the original file name?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are using a Maven repository format on a repository server it dictates the structure of that repository in terms of directory and filename.

This makes it deterministic to retrieve filenames based on the coordinates. If you want to have another filename just change the filename after you downloaded the file from the repo.

The same applies btw if you use an Ivy repository or any other repository. They have a set naming convention and structure. For ivy it can be configured but once configured the same convention applies to all files and it is also using GAV coordinates for naming files and folders.

Again.. the main thing is ... there is no reason to insist on a specific filename!

Comment: So if I used any other Maven repository like Archiva or Artifactory, I would still have to deal with this issue?

Comment: Yes. It is not really an "issue" though. It is a repository that allows you systematic access and not just a filesystem on a server where you can randomly dump stuff and then have to deal with a mess.